# MySQL date format change needed from data type as text

Tags: sql, mysql, date-format

I have a dataset collected from Kaggle in which there is a column named `DOB` where its data type is `TEXT`. Example: `Jan 30,2000`.

I want to change the date format of that particular column to be like `30-01-2000`.

How can I do this changes?

I tried using to change the data format from text to data and using the `date_format(columnname,%d-%m-%y)`

Comment: "...where its data type is TEXT.." -- First things first: Parse it into a proper `DATE` column. Dates don't have format; formatting is just part of the rendering while showing it to the end user.

Comment: how can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the current format, and `DATE_FORMAT()` to produce the new format:

```
UpDATE yourTable
SET columnname = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(columnname, '%b %d,%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Ideally you shouldn't store dates in text columns, you should use `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Formatting should be done in the UI, not in the raw data. It's also more efficient, since it's stored internally as a number.

Comment: i believe the below query will work from what you have said above,

update players_wc DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Player_DOB, '%b %d,%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y'));

where player_wc is the table name

Comment: You're missing `SET Player_DOB =`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: THANKS the changes worked. can i change the datatype to dat from text now?

Comment: You should use `%Y-%m-%d` format if you want to do that.

Comment: Acknowledged sir.

Comment: now i want to filter and pick the list of people from the player_DOB below the age 26 and so i use the below query to list the result. but my answer is irrelevant. please advice 


select player_DOB from players_wc
where player_DOB between '01-01-1997%' and '31-12-2005%';

Comment: That won't work, because it's comparing lexicographically. You need to use YYYY-MM-DD format if you want string comparison to be equivalent to date comparison.

Comment: You can't use wildcards like `%` in `BETWEEN`. It can only be used with `LIKE`.

Comment: how can i make this happen. please help

Comment: i have also tried using the below one,

select player_DOB from players_wc
where player_DOB < '01-01-1997%';

Comment: Convert the column to `DATE`. Then use `player_DOB BETWEEN '1997-01-01' AND '2005-12-31'`

Comment: You CANNOT use `%` in any comparisons like that. It only has meaning in `LIKE`.

Comment: If you have a new problem, post another question.

Comment: posted a  new question